# Search network drive without indexing it

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, search

Is legacy search available at all in Windows 7?
Indexing local drive is fine but indexing mapped network drive containing dozens of GBs is not on as is not searching common network locations all the time via network, server etc
Any ideas to share?

Answer (score 5):

Right-click your mapped drive. Click on properties in the opened menu. Then, uncheck "allow files on this drive to have contents indexed in addition to file properties." I believe that will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for legacy style search this Microsoft Answers post might help:

[Can I restore the XP style search to Windows 7?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/can-i-restore-the-xp-style-search-to-windows-7/e1601f87-8aa8-4992-b46e-562071aa1e7e)